# Calculate this determinant

Tags: determinant

Calculate the determinant of the matrix, which is obtained by crossing out crossing out columns i and j.

$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & x_{1} & \cdots & x_{1}^{n} & x_{1}^{n+1} \\
1 & x_{2} & \cdots & x_{2}^{n} & x_{2}^{n+1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & x_{n} & \cdots & x_{n}^{n} & x_{n}^{n+1}
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where is this question from? I am voting to close this question for a lack of context.

Comment: I added two lines and tried to expand the determinant into these two lines

Comment: This is called the [Vandermonde matrix](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde-Matrix).

Comment: See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/60971).

Comment: this is not the determinant of Vandermond

Comment: this matrix has size n × (n + 2)

Comment: Yes but after you delete two columns your matrix has the form addressed in the answer by David E Speyer that I linked to above.

Comment: Add two rows, $1,x,x^2,...,x^{n+1}$ and $1,y,y^2,...,y^{n+1}$ on top. The determinant of the resulting matrix is a Vandermonde of the numbers $x,y,x_1,x_2,...,x_n$. So, it is equal to $\prod_i(x_i-x)\prod_i(x_i-y)\prod_{i<j}(x_j-x_i)$. On the other hand, expanding the determinant according to the Laplace formula corresponding to the first two rows you get that it is equal to a polynomial $\sum_{i,j}D_{i,j}(x^iy^j-x^jy^i)$, where $D_{i,j}$ is the corresponding minor obtained deleting the first two rows and columns $i$ and $j$.

Comment: Now you can find those coefficients from the first expression using Vieta's formulas. $D_{i,j}$ is your determinant up to the sign in [Laplace's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#General_statement).

Comment: So, it is going to be something like $s_is_j\prod_{i<j}(x_j-x_i)$, where $s_i$ is the sum of products of $i$ of the $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik this matrix has size n × (n + 2)

Comment: This question is quite clearly distinct to and not answered by the "duplicate". Questions get closed for being duplicates when they are not far too often on Math.SE these days...